# Login freezes using FBSDK for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, fbsdkloginkit

I have an iOS app written in swift that uses Facebook login (FBSDK 4.11.0). The app is in production, and FB-login works perfectly.

However, while working on a new update I realised that I'm no longer able to sign in or register using FB. The login process stops after having authorized the application in the popup webview. It loads a blank page and stands still.

below code is the exact same code that is currently running perfectly on the version in the app store. I thought this might have something to do with the fact that the app is currently in dev, but after creating a beta and downloading it through testflight I still get the same problem.

Here is my code.

```
func fbLoginInitiate() {
        if hasSeenPermissionPopup(LoginType.Facebook){
            Globals.mixpanel.track("Initiated FB login")
            FBSDKLoginManager().logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_birthday"], fromViewController: self, handler: {(result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                if (error != nil) {
                    // Process error
                    self.removeFbData()
                } else if result.isCancelled {
                    // User Cancellation
                    self.removeFbData()
                } else {
                    //Success
                    if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email") && result.grantedPermissions.contains("public_profile") && result.grantedPermissions.contains("user_birthday") {
                        //Do work
                        self.fetchFacebookProfile()
                    } else {
                        Globals.mixpanel.track("Facebook login failed")
                        SweetAlert().showAlert("Ooops!", subTitle: "Noe gikk galt. Ta kontakt med Mojob dersom feilen vedvarer", style: AlertStyle.Warning)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Error is nil in the callback, and result only shows if I cancel the request. I've not done any changes to info.plist or any other settings that has to do with FB in the app.

If anyone has experienced anything similar, I would really appreciate hearing about how you solved the problem.

First part of the login works as expected

[image]

Second part freezes

[image]

Comment: Which iOS version are you on? Noticed the same on iOS 10..

Comment: I'm on version 9.3.2

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your AppDelegate correctly configured for the facebook SDK? If not you should add the following functions to it:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
           return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
       }

application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}
```

Se this issue for more information:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/72

In the issue they refer to this website where I found the correct setup:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#delegate